# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.' .For Glove dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stanford-nlp, kaggle

I am unable to figure out why i am getting this value error i tried with encoding ='utf8' but im still getting the same error,it gives me o/p as 50464it [00:02, 21543.68it/s] and than gives me value error

```
####################################################################
# find matches with glove 
####################################################################
GLOVE_DATASET_PATH = 'glove.840B.300d.txt'

from tqdm import tqdm
import string
embeddings_index = {}
f = open(GLOVE_DATASET_PATH)
word_counter = 0
for line in tqdm(f):
  values = line.split()
  word = values[0]
  if word in dictionary:
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32',)
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
  word_counter += 1
f.close()

print('Found %s word vectors matching enron data set.' % len(embeddings_index))
print('Total words in GloVe data set: %s' % word_counter)
```

```
50464it [00:02, 21543.68it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-701f9683d32e> in <module>
     13   word = values[0]
     14   if word in dictionary:
---> 15     coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32',)
     16     embeddings_index[word] = coefs
     17   word_counter += 1

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

I get this value error when i want to find out the words and total words in glove data

Comment: did you look at the first row of your file `'glove.840B.300d.txt'`, and are sure the data is not corrupted or in a different format?

Comment: I used Glove42B instead since that dataset had some preprocessing that matched ,maybe it wasn't working because the results weren't comparable.But when i changed the dataset it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I print the content of the entry for '.'. Apparently, there is more than one word vector for '.'. The first one has 300 dimensions and the second one has 302 dimensions with two dots in position 0 and 1 (hence the error). I don't know why there are two vectors for '.' or why there are dots in the vector.

```
.   300 ['0.012001', '0.20751', ...]

.   302 ['.', '.', '-0.1573', '-0.29517', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

reading the .txt file, you can ignore the extra line:

put your for loop in try and then ignore that line of the file, as below:

```
except:
    f.__next__()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is the entry ". . ." (not "...").

**Note** this error can be caused by other words also, e.g. `". . . . ."` and `"at name@domain.com"`.

When you're splitting the line

```
values = line.split()
values = ['.', '.', '.', float1, float2, ..., float300]
```

you are taking the first element as `word = values[0]`, and the rest as array of floats. However, since your `values[1:]` begins with '.', instead of a float, it will return this `ValueError`.

```
word = values[0]
if word in dictionary:
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32',)
```

**To solve this:**
insert a try-except notation to catch `". . ."`, among others. However, you need to keep in mind that you're assigning `word` **with spaces** as key to the dictionary `embeddings_index`. If you'll try to call this element by key, it will yield an error.

Here's an example on how the try-except can be used:

```
####################################################################
# find matches with glove 
####################################################################
GLOVE_DATASET_PATH = 'glove.840B.300d.txt'

from tqdm import tqdm
import string
embeddings_index = {}
f = open(GLOVE_DATASET_PATH)
word_counter = 0
for line in tqdm(f):
  try:

      values = line.split()
      word = values[0]
      if word in dictionary:
          coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32',)
          embeddings_index[word] = coefs
      word_counter += 1
  
   except:
       values = line.split()
       word = ". . ."
       if word in dictionary:
          coefs = np.asarray(values[3:], dtype='float32',)
          embeddings_index[word] = coefs
       word_counter += 1


f.close()
```